How to disable the chat selection window when opening a game in Telegram?
I am sending the game via the sendGame method:
Telegram::sendGame([
    'chat_id' => $chatId,
    'game_short_name' => 'game'
]);

When the player opens the game, a window appears at the bottom with a chat selection where the player can share the game.
The question is, how can I disable this window?

I know about the possibility of sending the game using other methods, but I am interested in the sendGame method.

Unfortunately, the telegram API doesn't specify anything for sendGame that would solely prevent this popup window. The protect_content method does seem to hold some promise, though, as it wouldn't make much sense for it to pull up the sharing window if sharing is disallowed. I imagine preventing sharing probably isn't the behavior you wish for, but there don't seem to be any less restrictive alternatives for the sendGame method.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendgame
